# plone: "to the top of the page"-link at the end of a collection list

Tags: plone

how can I add a "to the top" link at the end of a collection in plone?

This collection is in a collage. I thought of adding the article type "page" in a new row where I could use the HTML-Editor and use there an internal link to the top of the page.. But it seems inconvenient to me.

Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way could be using the Plone inner feature of the `document_actions` (a tool still available but not used anymore from Plone 4.0 and up).

Go to ZMI, access the `portal_actions` tool, the `document_actions`. Now add a new "CMF Action" from the form on the right.

The important information for you is the "URL (Expression)", that must be something like `string:#youranchortarget`. To fill every other field copy from existing actions.

If you need this link only for a content type or something like this, just play with the "Condition (Expression)".

Links inside this tool are displayed in the `plone.abovecontenttitle.documentactions` viewlet.

Comment: I did what you described. But the only changes that came is that there appeared a new link called the title I gave it in the ZMI. And this link appears on every article...

Comment: The fact that the link appear on every article is normal (see my answer, where I talk of the condition section).

About the link format: it's better you include here the whole configuration of the action as I don't understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want the link on every "page" item, then you could [customize](http://developer.plone.org/templates_css_and_javascripts/template_basics.html#overriding-templates) the default view's template.